# Adding tabs to CTabCtrl in MFC

Tags: c++, tabs, mfc, ctabctrl

I am trying to add a CTabCtrl into my MFC application.  I am trying to follow the MSDN directly.

[image: MSDN Adding Tab]

*[MSDN: Adding Tabs to Tab Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcz8wdb3.aspx)

Here is what I have tried:

`DDX_Control(pDX, TAB1, m_TabCtrl);`

```
TC_ITEM ti;
ti.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
ti.pszText = _T("First Tab");

m_TabCtrl.InsertItem(0,&ti);
```

I am receiving the following error message:
[image: Assertion Fail]

If I hit ignore, my CTabCtrl is shown, but without any tabs (just a gray square).  If I hit retry, I get the breakpoint at:

```
_AFXCMN_INLINE BOOL CTabCtrl::SetItem(int nItem, TCITEM* pTabCtrlItem)
{ ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (BOOL)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, TCM_SETITEM, nItem, (LPARAM)pTabCtrlItem); }
```

I have tried adding the header `#include "afxcmn.h"` but it does not change anything.

I am simply trying to get named tabs to show on my application as a first step.  Eventually I wish for the tabs to show modeless dialogs.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Is there a better way to use tabs in MFC?

Comment: Have you clicked Retry to step through the code?

Comment: Clicking Retry on that dialog will lead you more useful debugging info.

Comment: Where in your code is the call to InsertItem?  It can't be in DoDataExchange, and it needs to be in a function that is called after the dialog is initialized and control windows are created.

Comment: I have updated  my question with debugging info.  I make the call to InsertItem  after `OnInitDialog()
{` of my main Dialog's class.

Comment: At the moment, my m_TabCtrl is not trying to link to any dialogs.  I am just trying to get the text of each tab to show.

Comment: If what you want is a tabbed looking dialog structure, take a look at CPropertySheet and CPropertyPage.  It might be a little easier for you.

Comment: More than likely, you have an invalid handle (m_hwnd) when executing the InsertItem command.  That would imply your tab control was not created correctly before you tried to execute the insert command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your information provided, it's clear that it is ASSERTing on IsWindow(m_hWnd).  So that means the window for your tab control has not been created yet when you call InsertItem().

Are you putting the CTabCtrl in a CDialog derived class or in some other CWnd derived class?  Have you set a breakpoint on your DDX_Control() line of code to be sure 1) it is actually being called, and 2) that it is successful?  I have a feeling that it is not even being called, because if it was, then you would have a valid m_hWnd, or you would get an ASSERT() at the point of your DDX_Control() call to say that it failed.